# why my swing just hangs when I click button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a form coded in Swing with a JButton which I click to get an action done. But when I click it, my frame hangs.  I can't exit it until I end it using the taskbar.  What is the problem?  Here is my code:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String[] stopwords = {"a", "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhere", "still",
            "such", "system", "take", "ten", "than", "that", "the", "their", 
            "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter",
            "thereby", "therefore", "therein", "thereupon", "these", "they",
            "thickv", "thin", "third", "this", "those", "though", "three",
            "through", "throughout", "thru", "thus", "to", "together", "too",
            "top", "toward", "towards", "twelve", "twenty", "two", "un",
            "under", "until", "up", "upon", "us", "very", "via", "was", "we",
            "well", "were", "what", "whatever", "when", "whence", "whenever",
            "where", "whereafter", "whereas","whereby", "wherein", "whereupon",
            "wherever", "whether", "which", "while","whither", "who", "whoever",
            "whole", "whom", "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without",
            "would", "yet", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves",
            "contact", "grounds", "buyers",  "tried", "said,", "plan", "value",
            "principle.", "forces", "sent:", "is,", "was", "like", "discussion",
            "tmus", "diffrent.", "layout", "area.", "thanks", "thankyou",
            "hello", "bye", "rise","fell","fall","psqft.","http://","km","miles"};
    try {
        Scanner fip1 = new Scanner(new File(selectedFile));
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("d:/StopWords.txt");
        while(fip1.hasNext()) {
            int flag=1;
            String s1=fip1.next();
            s1=s1.toLowerCase();
            for(int i=0;i<stopwords.length;i++){
                if(s1.equals(stopwords[i])) {
                    flag=0;
                }
            }
            if(flag!=1) {
             // System.out.println(s1);
             // jTextArea1.append("\n"+s1);
             PrintStream p=new PrintStream(out);
             p.println(s1);  
             p.close();
         }
     }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"STOP WORD REMOVAL IS DONE");        
     } catch(Exception e){
         System.err.println("cannot read file");
     }
}
```

Comment: What does `selectedFile` contain? It might just be a bunch of tokens and the operation is very long.

Comment: what size do your input text files have?

Comment: Because Swing is single-threaded, so it cannot update the UI when you block the thread with long-running operations.

Comment: yes it contains strings and few kb

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: How much did you actually wait? Did you debug the code? I agree with @Robin's concern.

Comment: You seem to have an extra closing bracket in the code.  Is this intentional?  Are there any errors thrown in the code when you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a loop, Java has very good debugging services, often built into your IDE.  You should try those to see if you can track down what's happening.  Put a stop where you process the button and follow the code fom here.

You could use a Hashmap for your list of stop words as well, but that's not your bug, just an improvement.

Edit: as @robin pointed out Swing actions must end quickly.

Comment: help me to have a example to add hashmap

Comment: There are dozens of HashMap examples online, here's the official Oracle Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the scanner usage. why not using outputStream?
regardless of the problem- you should use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to do the dirty IO work, and keep the UI responsive.